# Migrating data,Tables,stored procedures from MS SQL SERVER 2008 to MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

how to transfer all the tables and stored procedures from ms sql server 2008 to mysql along with the data in them?i have tried all the tools mentioned in the other links but none of them seems to work with the stored procedures,any one who has done this before can be really helpful.

Comment: Not an answer, but keep in mind that mysql and sql server have differences in sql syntax in many cases. some stored procedures will have to be adapted manually in order to work properly.

Comment: The project i am currently working on contains more than 1000 procedures,as there is too much work being done on automating processes these days,i am hoping i can find help from some guru in here ,thanks a lot for replying to the post.

Comment: What language do you use for the progrma or the project is only in database

Comment: For the tables/data, have you looked at SSIS?  If you have more than 1000 stored procedures, you might need to comb through each of them to change the syntax.